# Python - Selenium: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

I'm trying to find out, why the following error is being raised:

```
Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated
```

I want to find the `next` button and click it.

This is the page: [example page](http://www.sreality.cz/hledani/prodej/byty/praha-2,praha-3?stavba=cihlova&vlastnictvi=osobni&strana=1)

I have this code in my `driver` class:

```
def click_next(self):
    try:
        self.driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//li[@class="paging-item"]/a').click()
    except:
        raise
        return False
```

Do you know where is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why are you using `xpath` to search for a *class name* when there is a method exactly for that, `find_element_by_class_name`?

`PhantomJS` often behaves in a weird way. Many times when an `Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated` it's because of the *window size*. Try re-sizing the window, that worked for me (tested on `Ubuntu 14.04` with `Phantom JS 1.9.8`).

```
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'http://www.sreality.cz/hledani/prodej/byty/praha-2,praha-3?stavba=cihlova&vlastnictvi=osobni&strana=1'

browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()
browser.set_window_size(1920, 1080)  # choose a resolution big enough
browser.get(url)

next_arrow = browser.find_element_by_class_name('paging-next')
next_arrow.click()
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the below xpath instead? your xpath actually returns 4 matches.

```
"//li[@class='paging-item']//a[@class='btn-paging-pn icof icon-arr-right paging-next']"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your XPath query returns 4 elements. You must know that Selenium takes the first element by default in this case. If it happens that such element is not visible then you cannot interact with it by using click.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the location of your element. Assume, it has negative numbers. Scroll window, so an element is in visible area.

I had the same issue, element's location attribute was (807, -30). The code below fixed this issue

```
    driver.get(url)
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 60);")
    element = findElement(driver, "//button[contains(text(),'some text')]", WAIT_IN_SEC)

    element.click()
```